# Use JDBC connect to databrick default cluster and read table into pyspark dataframe. All the column turned into same as column name

Tags: dataframe, azure, pyspark, jdbc, databricks

I have table stored in databrick cluster default database.

my_table2:

[image]

I used code like below to Use JDBC connect to databrick default cluster and read table into pyspark dataframe

```py
url = 'jdbc:databricks://[workspace domain]:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=[path];AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=[your_access_token]'

driver_class = 'com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver'
# create a DataFrame by querying the MySQL database
df_1 = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
.option("url", url)\
.option("driver", driver_class)\
.option("dbtable", 'my_table2')\
.load()

df_1.show()
```

The final df_1 dataframe become

```
+----+
|name|
+----+
|name|
|name|
|name|
+----+
```

Please help!

the final result should be

```
+----+
|name|
+----+
|John|
|Jane|
|Bob |
+----+
```

[those are all my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1spU2.png)

Comment: which databricks are you using? azure or aws?

Comment: I am using Azure

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the JDBC syntax:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<server_name>.database.windows.net:1433;database<database_name>;user=<user_name>;password=<Password>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

I reproduce the same in the environment got this output.

> **Connect azure Databricks with azure SQL using JDBC**

**Code:**

```
url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://<server_name>.database.windows.net:1433;database<database_name>;user=<user_name>;password=<Password>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;'

driver_class = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'

df_1 = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("driver", driver_class).option("dbtable", 'table1').load()

df_1.show()

# Create a view or table
df_1.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table2")
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

> **Update:**

Try this alternative approach without using JDBC URL. It's working fine with the default database for the databrick cluster running in my notebook

**Connection string**: Go to SQL Warehouse -> Select your cluster -> go to connection details.

**Generating Access token:** Go to user setting -> generate access_ token

As per [Ms_Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/python-sql-connector#examples),

**As you can see, this is my SQL table:**

[image]

**I reproduce same in my environment. I got required result as below:**

```
from databricks import sql
import os

conn = sql.connect( 
                     server_hostname = "<Host_name>",
                     http_path = "<Path>",
                     access_token = "<Access_token>")

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * from P123")
display(cursor.fetchall())

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there!
Just want to follow up your question, the database I tried to connect to is the default database for databrick cluster running in my notebook. The jdbc I downloaded is from this [link](https://www.databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download). that is the reason I set up driver class like `com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Hi @yu zhang, check above update with default database : )

Comment: I used `df_2 =  spark.sql('select * from my_table2')` the dataframe shows correctly. just cannot use jdbc connection get the correct table. Do you think this is partitioning problem?

Comment: please also check out my edited questions. I took the screenshot about all my tests

Comment: hi @yuzhang, I followed same test results in my environment, its working fine. once check your jdbc URL, table name and also follow above approach. It will solve your problem.